# Module import errors (Windows)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I refactored some of my code and put it in individual directories, and suddenly the interpreter can't find any of my custom modules.

My package structure looks like this:

```
etl3
    __init__.py
    inst_config
        __init__.py
        config3.py
    inst_utils
        __init__.py
        etc...
    jira
        filetorun.py
    etc...
```

I'm trying to run the file in the jira directory.  When it was just under the `etl3\` directory it can find it due to them being in the same directory.  Once nested however, it cannot find them.

I run the python interpreter, and print my `sys.path`.  I can see the path to `C:\etl3\inst_config\` on there, which is why I'm confused as to why my file in the `jira` directory can't find it.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: `ImportError: No module named 'inst_config'`.  That module is just where it's been for the last however long.

Comment: On my `sys.path` I can see the module...  I'm not sure why python isn't correctly finding my module

Comment: you need to show the actual structure of your project, and how you are trying to use import.  The way packages work is [well documented](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages).  If you cannot answer your own question from the documentation then add much more information to your question.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen I have updated my OP as requested.  I am thoroughly stumped even after reading the documentation.

Comment: naive question but, do you have your `PYTHONPATH` set properly?

Comment: @HuguesFontenelle I think so, but I have my module set in the `PATH` as well.  When I run `sys.path` I can see the modules I have placed there.  Then I have another variable called `PYTHONPATH` where I have also placed the paths to those locations.

Comment: so let me get this strait... you have been running your script from `C:\etl3\ ` for a while and after reorganizing your project you are wondering why you cannot make imports in the same way as if `C:\etl3\ ` was on `sys.path`? If you include `C:\etl3\inst_config\ ` on the path that will let you import modules **inside** the folder, not the folder itself.

Comment: you may also want to look at [Relative imports in Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3) for why running a submodule of a package doesn't make all that much sense

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen The command that was failing was `from inst_config import config3`.  So that should be covered by having `C:\etl3\inst_config` on the `PATH`

Comment: if `config3` is in a folder that is on `sys.path` then you would just do `import config3` that is how the PATH works!   Otherwise put `C:\etl3` on your path.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen You solved it.  If you want to write an answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `inst_config` folder is on the path you would simply import the files from it directly:

```
import config3
```

However when `C:\etl3\` is on your PATH you can import modules that are defined there, in this case it would be the package `inst_config` and a submodule of it:

```
import inst_config.config3
# or
from inst_config import config3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from etl3.inst_config import YourClassHere
```

(recommended), or

```
import etl3.inst_config.config3
```

https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages

Comment: Hmm, I tried this as well and it didn't work.  I'm using Python3.5 if that makes a difference in this case.